# Getting the names of all the instance fields used inside the equals function

Tags: java, equals

I am working on a project related to hash functions in Java. The user is required to **override** the equals function and provide us with it. While **overriding** equals he may use a subset of all the instance fields of the class which I am considering as the important fields of the object. How can I extract the names of all the fields that the user uses inside the equals method? 
I am able to get the names of all the fields using the Reflection API but I only want those fields that have been used inside the equals method to compare the objects.(Using reflection is not a constraint, I just want a way to solve the problem.)

Comment: Reflection cannot inspect the implementation of methods.  What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: Using reflection is not a constraint. Any working method is fine.

Comment: I would be shocked if such a method existed at all, frankly.

Comment: In the worst case, I will have to use some kind of a parser. Correct me ,if I am wrong.

Comment: I mean, at runtime you can't look up the source code of other classes. A runtime solution may be literally impossible.  A compile time solution...maybe?

Comment: This idea seems wrong headed in every way.  I would advise you not to do  this.  Get better developers for your classes and better libraries for your dependencies.  Not knowing how to override equals and hashCode properly, after all the years that Joshua Bloch's book has been in print, is a sure sign of incompetence.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Our professor suggested that the eclipse IDE may be of some help here but I am not quite sure how. Do you have any suggestions about that?

Comment: How do you know the user actually did override the equals function?  Is the user overriding from your base class?  If yes, is your base class equals() method flagged as abstract?  Can you require the sub-classes to implement an interface such as ImportantFields?

Comment: I am well aware of the contract between equals() and hashCode() method in Java. Instead of emphasizing on that, I would appreciate if you could suggest me a way to solve the problem assuming that the user has overridden the equals method.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do such a thing with the reflection API that I know of.

The only way that I'm aware of is to read the code.

If your project depends on this as a requirement, I fear that you'll have to reconsider it.

The correct thing to do is to override `equals` and `hashCode` together, as defined by Joshua Bloch in [Effective Java chapter 3](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy252/project_old/Chapter3.pdf).  The class designer should be providing you with the proper `hashCode` using the fields that they decided to use.

Perhaps your scheme could use that `hashCode` returned value as a start.

The problem is that you have no control over what the developers of libraries you depend on will do.

If you do have that kind of control, because you only care about classes that *you* write, then it's another discussion.

Comment: You could use a bytecode library to see which fields are accessed by the code in the `equals()` method, though I wouldn't recommend it. It may be complicated by the fact that the code might use getter methods rather than direct field access.

Comment: @duffymo I am actually following the book. But my project aims to override the hashCode method automatically for the user provided he/she supplies the implementation for the equals method. While overriding, I want to only consider the important fields rather than all the fields present in the class. And here by important fields, I mean all those fields which have been used in the equals method.

Comment: Bad idea.  You cannot do such a thing for 3rd party developers and get it right.  If they aren't overriding hashCode when they override equals they aren't doing it right.  Better to find proper libraries than try to band aid over bad behavior.

Comment: I am well aware of the contract between equals() and hashCode() method in Java. Instead of emphasizing on that, I would appreciate if you could suggest me a way to solve the problem assuming that the user has overridden the equals method.

Comment: Sorry, I have no answers for you.  I think your idea is wrong.